# How to send data to parent method from components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to send parameters to parent method from component.
But I got these error message "[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteClicked' of undefined"

I want to send parameters to deleteClicked function from component.

My javascript code is below.

```
var sablon = Vue.extend({
    props: ["name"],
    template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click=this.$parent.deleteClicked(name) style = "margin: 3px;" > {{ name }}</button > '
});

var viewmodel = new Vue({
    el: '#divimiz',
    components: { 'sablonx': sablon },
    data: {
        names: ['Mary', 'John', 'Robert'],
        newname: '',
        test: "selam",
    },
    methods: {
        addname: function () {
            this.names.push(this.newname);
            this.newname = '';
        },
        deleteClicked: function (item) {
            var x = this.names.indexOf(item);

            if (x > -1) {

                this.names.splice(x, 1);
            }
        },
    },

});
```

And my html code is below,

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="divimiz" class="container">
    <div class="row">


    <sablonx v-for="name in names" v-bind:name="name"></sablonx>
    <br>

    <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="newname" style="width: 400px; margin: 5px;">
    <button class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="addname">Click to add name</button>


</div>


<script src="x.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `this` keyword in  your template.

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-warning"
  v-on:click="$parent.deleteClicked(name)"
  style="margin: 3px;">
  {{ name }}
</button >
```

Also, I recommand to use [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to achieve what you want to do.

```html
<!-- Children component -->
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-warning"
  v-on:click="$emit('delete', name)"
  style="margin: 3px;">
  {{ name }}
</button >

<!-- Parent component -->
<sablonx
  v-for="name in names"
  :key="name"
  :name="name"
  @delete="deleteClicked"/>
```

You can see no params is passed visually to the function `deleteClicked`, but what actually happens is that it listens to the `delete` event, and will apply the data passed from the event to the function. Another way of writing it would be:

```html
<!-- Parent component -->
<sablonx
  v-for="name in names"
  :key="name"
  :name="name"
  @delete="deleteClicked($event)"/>
```

where `$event` is the variable containing the name you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer data from a child component to a parent, you'd want to use $emit (Unlike when passing data from parent to child - then you'd wanna use props, or if you pass data from one component to another, you can use an Event Bus, which is not always recommended but that's another subject)

Anyways, the code is:

```
this.$emit('youremitname', payload);
```

You want to have this code whenever you want to emit the data, for example if you want to emit the data after a click of a button, you'd want to have this inside a function. (If you're using it it in the @click attribute, no need for the "this" keyword, simply write:

```
$emit('youremitname', payload)
```

This will transfer the data to the parent, however make sure you listen for it where you use your component, for example if your component name inside the parent componenet is 'Customers', then your code should look like this:

```
<Customers @youremitname></Customers>
```

You can also listen for an emit in the "mounted" or "created" lifecycle hook using:

```
$emit.$on('youremitname', passAFunctionHere).
```

For more information check out Vue docs - [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

Comment: I modified my code like this but still not working

template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click=this.$emit(deleteClicked, name) style = "margin: 3px;" > {{ name }}</button > '

Comment: No need to use the "this" keyword. Simply write: "$emit('deleteClicked', name)" (make sure to use parentheses in the name).

Comment: I cannot use "$ emit ('deleteClicked', name)" because I use the template in single quotes. there are too many quotes.

template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click="$emit('deleteClicked', name)" style = "margin: 3px;" > {{ library }}</button > '

Comment: You can escape it with `\``

Comment: @nook  I tried it but it couldn't escape. Could you modify my code with this character 
template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click="$emit('deleteClicked', name)" style = "margin: 3px;" > {{ library }}</button > '

Comment: Try to use this code:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click="$emit('deleteClicked', name)" style = "margin: 3px;" > {{ library }}</button >`

And in the html write:

<div v-html="yourVariableName"></div>

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the character I wanted to show you how to escape. It's not `\`` but ``\``(backslash)